# Which format should the version constant of my project have

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Ive seen lots of stuff

```
Foo::VERSION::STRING
Foo::VERSION
Foo::Version
```

any suggestions what the best/most-common default is ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, `Foo::Version` seems wrong to me. That implicates that version is a Class or a Module, but should be a constant, as first two of your examples.

Apart from that, there is no golden rule here. Here are a few examples:

[Rails](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/version.rb):

```
    Rails::VERSION::STRING
```

(Note: a module `VERSION` with all capitals.)

[SimpleForm](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/blob/master/lib/simple_form/version.rb):

```
    SimpleForm::VERSION
```

[Nokogiri](https://github.com/tenderlove/nokogiri/blob/master/lib/nokogiri/version.rb):

```
    Nokogiri::VERSION
```

[RSpec](https://github.com/rspec/rspec/blob/master/lib/rspec/version.rb):

```
    RSpec::Version::STRING
```

(Note, a module `Version`, compare with Rails above.)

[Cucumber](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/blob/master/lib/cucumber/platform.rb):

```
    Cucumber::VERSION
```

[SimpleForm](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/blob/master/lib/simple_form/version.rb):

```
    SimpleForm::VERSION
```

Most of the above have their version defined in the `lib/[name]/version.rb` file, except for Rails, which has a `version.rb` in the root of the project, and Cucumber, which has buried it in the `lib/cucumber/platform.rb` file.

Also note that all of the above use `String`s as a version. (Rails even concatenates `MAJOR`, `MINOR`, `TINY`, and `PRE` constants into a single `VERSION` constant.) This allows for easy comparison of versions:

```
    "1.2.3" > "0.4.2"  # => true
    "1.2.3" > "1.2.2"  # => true
    "1.2.3" > "1.2"    # => true
```

However, such a comparison fails when you run into double digits for the patch level:

```
    "1.2.3" > "1.2.12" # => true
```

To me, defining `Foo::VERSION` is your best bet, define it in `lib/foo/version.rb`, and make it a `String` value.

Comment: And a few references that might be useful as well: [Making ruby gems](http://timelessrepo.com/making-ruby-gems) by Steve Klabnik, [RubyGems spec.version](http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/20#version) and [RubyGems versioning policy](http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/7).